# Complex number inequality on the unit disk

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

This was posted on another website, but there are no responses so far:

Let $a,b$ and $c$ be complex numbers such that $|az^2+bz+c| \le 1$ for $z$ in the closed unit disk. Show that $|bc| \le \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{16}$.